# Sample Code for usage of BasicMDCAdapter class for java.util.logging framework

Tags: java, slf4j, java.util.logging, mdc

I am basically trying to add MDC support in java.util.logging framework without using any slf4j to JUL bridge alternative. In the Javadoc of BasicMDCAdapter it is mentioned that "Basic MDC implementation, which can be used with logging systems that lack out-of-the-box MDC support".

I can't seem to find any sample which can help me in same. Can anyone tell me how can I take advantage of BasicMDCAdapter class to add MDC support in JUL.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution. Actually, it was pretty simple.

To access BasicMDCAdapter through MDC, following code can help

```
    MDCAdapter adapter = MDC.getMDCAdapter();
    adapter = new BasicMDCAdapter();
    MDC.put("key", "value");
```

This way, the key is set in the current thread's context.

Hope it helps someone as it did me !!!